# Convert String Date to Object

Tags: php, datetime, object

My date is **"04 February 2017 - 06:35"**

How can I Change into Date Object ?

I tried

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', "04 February 2017 - 06:35");
```

But its not Working

Comment: what you want in output?

Comment: @BhavinSasapra I want date object of given date, I want to store in Database.

Comment: You use the right function you just want to specify the date format correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time and the format should be corresponding! Your format is `d M Y - H:i`.

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y - H:i', "04 February 2017 - 06:35");
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks @Haotian Liu

Answer (score -1):

> Try This

You cannot get direct object of string you have to use date_format

```
$date = date_create_from_format('j M Y - H:i', "04 February 2017 - 06:35");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```